# How to disable the arrow keys navigation in QTableWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Currently, I'm writing a combat manager for DnD-like games. The characters active in a combat are displayed in a table. For this table, I'm using a `QTableWidget`. 
Now I've implemented a feature allowing a user to navigate through this table using the `Enter`-Key. If the user gets to the end of the table and hits `Enter` again, the next highlighted row is the first one, so the next round begins. 
Beside the `Enter`-Key, navigating the row using the `Arrow`-Keys (`Up` and `Down`) is currently also possible. But I don't want this. The navigation should be possible using only the `Enter`-Key.
Therefore my question is: How can I disable the `Arrow`-Keys inside a `QTableWidget`? The things I've tried so far are:

1. Implementing a `keyPressEvent`-function, which also handles the `Enter`-key. This function should just return if one of the `Arrow`-Keys is pressed, but navigation (which means selection of rows) with these keys is still possible. The code is here:

```
void TableWidget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event) {
     // ...
     // Code for the other keys
     // ...
     if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Down || event->key() == Qt::Key_Up) {
          return;
     }
}
```

This is also the case if I'm adding the `ignore`-function using the following code:

```
if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Down || event->key() == Qt::Key_Up) {
     event->ignore();
     return;
}
```

2. I tried to implement an `eventFilter` function (example is [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html)). In this case, this function returns `false` if the `Up` or `Down`-Key is pressed, but navigating the rows is still possible.

Right now, I'm out of options. Is it even possible to disable these keys inside a `QTableWidget`? Or did I miss something? Is the usage of a `QTableWidget` even the best idea? Thanks for any answers!

EDIT 2: Now I've tried it using a subclass of the `QTableWidget`. The code for this class goes as follows:

MyTableWidget.h

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class MyTableWidget : public QTableWidget {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyTableWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MyTableWidget();

private:
    void setupTable();
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);

    QTableWidget *tableWidget;
};
```

MyTableWidget.cpp

```
#include "MyTableWidget.h"

MyTableWidget::MyTableWidget(QWidget *parent)
{
    setupTable();
}

void MyTableWidget::setupTable() {
    // Allocate widget and create a column
    tableWidget = new QTableWidget(this);
    tableWidget->setColumnCount(1);
    // Create some rows
    tableWidget->insertRow( tableWidget->rowCount() );
    tableWidget->insertRow( tableWidget->rowCount() );
}

// This function calls some functions for certain keys
void MyTableWidget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event) {
    if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Down || event->key() == Qt::Key_Up) {
        event->ignore();
        return;
    }
}

MyTableWidget::~MyTableWidget()
{
}
```

The modified `mainwindow.h` now just has the constructor with the following code:

```
myTableWidget = new MyTableWidget(this);
setCentralWidget(myTableWidget);
```

EDIT 1: A minimum example will be provided. This will create a small table with 1 column and 2 rows.

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtWidgets>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    void setupTable();
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);

    QTableWidget *tableWidget;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setupTable();
}

void MainWindow::setupTable() {
    // Allocate widget and create a column
    tableWidget = new QTableWidget();
    tableWidget->setColumnCount(1);
    // Set this widget to central
    setCentralWidget(tableWidget);
    // Create some rows
    tableWidget->insertRow( tableWidget->rowCount() );
    tableWidget->insertRow( tableWidget->rowCount() );
}

void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event) {
    if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Down || event->key() == Qt::Key_Up) {
        event->ignore();
        return;
    }
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(TablTest LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)

add_executable(TableTest
    main.cpp
    mainwindow.cpp
    mainwindow.h
)

target_link_libraries(TableTest PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets)
```

Comment: For me the `keyPressEvent` reimplementation disables the key navigation. So, it should be something else. Prepare a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Alright, I've edited the question. An MRE is provided now.

Comment: Why do you insist on using `QTableWidget`? In Edit 2 you have: `QTableWidget *tableWidget;`. Of course it won't work. See my updated answer.

Comment: aaaah, now I finally understand what you've meant. Works like a charm now. Thanks for the detailed example! :-)

Comment: You are very welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Cause

You are reimplementing the `keyPressEvent` of the `QMainWindow`, not the `QTableWidget`:

```
void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event) {
    if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Down || event->key() == Qt::Key_Up) {
        event->ignore();
        return;
    }
}
```

### Solution

1. Subclass `QTableWidget`, e.g. `MyTableWidget`
2. In the subclass `MyTableWidget` reimplement the `QTableWidget::keyPressEvent`
3. Instead of `tableWidget = new QTableWidget();` create an object of your subclass, `MyTableWidget`, i.e `tableWidget = new MyTableWidget();`

### Example

Here is an example I have written for you to demonstrate how the proposed solution could be implemented:

**MyTableWidget.h**

```
#include <QTableWidget>

class MyTableWidget : public QTableWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyTableWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

protected:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event) override;
};
```

**MyTableWidget.cpp**

```
MyTableWidget::MyTableWidget(QWidget *parent)
{
}

void MyTableWidget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event) {
    if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Down
        || event->key() == Qt::Key_Up) {
        event->ignore();
        return;
    } else {
        QTableWidget::keyPressEvent(event);
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
#include "MyTableWidget.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setupTable();
}

void MainWindow::setupTable() {
    tableWidget = new MyTableWidget();
    tableWidget->setColumnCount(1);
    setCentralWidget(tableWidget);
    // Create some rows
    tableWidget->insertRow( tableWidget->rowCount() );
    tableWidget->insertRow( tableWidget->rowCount() );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort for this answer! I've tried as you suggested and created a subclass, reimplementing the `keyPressEvent`. I've also changed the constructor in the `mainwindow.cpp`. All this is shown in EDIT 2. It still does not work. Did I miss or oversee something?